# $http.get() takes time to load. need better way to write this

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

i am new to angular. i try to build a sample site. i used below code

in my index.html

```
    <a href="#/offer" ng-repeat="menus in menulist" ><div class="menuname" ng-class="{blue:hover}" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false" >{{ menus.menu }}</div></a>
```

in my routeprovider.js

```
angular.module('techzeek').config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    controller: 'RouteController',
    templateUrl:'assets/views/mypageview.html'
})
.when('/:id', {
    controller: 'RouteController1',
    templateUrl:'assets/views/mypageview.html'
})
});
```

in my offercontroller.js

```
angular.module('techzeek').controller('RouteController',function($scope,$http){   $http.get('http://techzeek.com/assets/files/rechargecontrollerdetails.json').success(function(data){
     $scope.offerdetails=data;
     });
     });


angular.module('techzeek').controller('RouteController1',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
$http.get('http://techzeek.com/assets/files/'+$routeParams.id+'.json').success(function(data){
     $scope.offerdetails=data;
     });
     });
```

when i click above link. it will take some time to load the content. how can i avoid this. or what is better way to do this??

[**look sample**](http://techzeek.com/)

Comment: If you're retrieving data from the server and then re-rendering the UI it's always going to take some time.  How long do you think it should take?

Comment: Take a look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) for state definitions and `resolve` config for performing some asynchronous operations before the view is redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache your data so it will be available after the first request
for example you can put the content of the template in the head of the page (load it to the head using server side code) like that

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="assets/views/mypageview.html">
  Content of the template.
</script>
```

that why Angular will not load the external file.
You can also do the same for your JSON data like that

```
<script>
   var JSON_DATA = ....
</script>
```

so you will not need to use $http to load your data
you can read more about this system here
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script